# Trying to Convert Columns into rows for small devices

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

**[I am studying this tutorial to convert columns into rows for small devices. Please click it](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)**

Problem is: it shows all columns and rows in in line. Am I missing anything?

**[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgE4vkc6EyHsBiVRZ5Mf?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        User Name
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Email Address
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        First Name
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Last Name
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Is Active
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        User Name 1
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Email Address 1
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        First Name 1
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Last Name 1
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Is Active 1
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js dependencies**

> angular.min.js
>
> angular-route.min.js
>
> angular-animate.js
>
> angular-touch.js
>
> ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js

**Css**

> bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.col` class ([Auto-layout column](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)) is new to Bootstrap 4.x, and the plunker is including Bootstrap 3.x.

Use `.col` in 4.x: [Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/e4rcIlXYa9)

or, use of the specific grid units (`.col-md-*`) in 3.x

Comment: 4 alpha 6 on CDN http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css but don't think it's working yet with Angular Bootstrap

Comment: Sir, I changed as per your instructions and it is almost done. Actually, what I was trying to achieve was to show column name and it's value in same cell and then next column name and it's value in same cell next row in small devices...but so far it started to work....columns are changing into rows perfectly....Upvoted

Comment: anyways thanks for the help. I am closing this question. Thanks a lot for the help.